# How do I find if a database record exists?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to see if a record exist within a table before i write it to a file  but i keep getting a error

```
string InformationCheck = "Select FName,LName from Customer where FName ='" + this.f_Name.Text + "' and LName = '" + l_Name.Text + "'";

OleDbCommand InfoCheck = new OleDbCommand(InformationCheck, conn);

String strResult = String.Empty;

try
{

    conn.Open();
    strResult = (String)InfoCheck.ExecuteScalar();

    if (strResult.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dose Not Exist");
        AddInfo.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
        this.Hide();
        f1.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exists");

    }                    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex + "");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: You're doing (String)ExecuteScalar() but are asking for 2 items back.

Comment: Until you specify the error message: is there a space between the closing single quote of FName and the "and" keyword? in the text above it is hard to tell.

Comment: What's your error ????

Comment: @Jonesy - this is not true. Exec Scalar returns top-most, left-most cell. But will not break

Comment: You are right, I just went through the documentation.  I updated my comment.

Comment: @WLin 
System.Null.ReferenceException : object reference not set to a instance of an object

At login.create.make_Account_click (Object sender ,EventArgs e) in e:\school\comp123\login\login\login\create.cs:line 132

Comment: Specify which line in example code you getting error.

Comment: Am I the only one worried about the SQL injection possibility?

Comment: Most likely problem with `AddInfo.ExecuteReader();` `AddInfo` is command , which may be not initialized.

Comment: How would I initialize addinfo ? @T.S.

Comment: Same as InfoCheck = `new OleDbCommand("insert into....", conn)`
But then you want to call `AddInfo.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Just a suggestion, if this is a new project, why not use Entity Framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Comment: @Jeroen1984 i didn't know that this existed thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i got my problem resolved by changing the .ExecuteReader(); to .ExecuteNonQuery();

it now check if it in the database, and if its not the information is entered into the table.

Comment: good to hear, you now have more time to read this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and if time permits http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev

Comment: Thanks you very much going to have a look over of these @philsoady